# Chromatic number for "great circle" graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I would like to calculate the chromatic number for a great circle graph.  I tried this example in [this link](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChromaticPolynomial.html).
I first tried to calculate the chromatic number for `PetersenGraph` as in the example but *Mathematica* did not give me the same result.
I saw another example in [this link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10415/the-following-code-doesnt-seem-to-work-finding-chomatic-number-of-undirected-gr).
It worked for the example, but when I applied it to my great circle graph it did not work.  Is there some special functions for great circle graphs?

Comment: I think you should post your **code/trial**. In that case, others maybe help you by runing and editing your code.

Answer (score 4):

For calculating the chromatic number of *any* graph, you can simply do the following:

```
ChromaticNumber[g_] := MinValue[{z, z > 0 && ChromaticPolynomial[g, z] > 0}, z, Integers];
```

That is, the above finds the smallest integer such that the input graph has at least one proper coloring.

Do note, however, that this method should be very slow and practically unusable for anything but small graphs. If your graphs are a little larger and/or harder to color, it's a better idea to try e.g., `IGraphM`.

Answer (score 2):

IGraph/M includes several functions for colouring. See the Graph Colouring sections of its documentation.

To compute the chromatic number, use `IGChromaticNumber`.

```
g = PetersenGraph[];

IGChromaticNumber[g]
(* 3 *)
```

We can also produce an actual colouring.

```
Graph[g, VertexSize -> Large, GraphStyle -> "BasicBlack"] // 
 IGVertexMap[ColorData[101], VertexStyle -> IGMinimumVertexColoring]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I presume by "great circle graph" you mean a `CycleGraph`.

Note that:

> `ChromaticPolynomial[g,k]` gives the number of vertex colorings of *g*
>   with *k* colors.

```
i = 4;
k = 2;
ChromaticPolynomial[CycleGraph[i], k]
```

2

```
i = 10;
k = 4;
ChromaticPolynomial[CycleGraph[i], k]
```

59052

If instead you mean the graph defined by the intersection points of great circles on a sphere, then you must define your graph first, then compute `ChromaticPolynomial[g,k]`.

Comment: yes, I mean great circles on a sphere. I defined my graph and when I use the ChromaticPolynomial command it returns that: ChromaticPolynomial[
 PlanarGraphPL[{{0, {{-19.7169, 3.80447}, {-36.8575, 
      8.29989}, {-53.6898, 13.8393}, {-70.1502, 20.4017}, {-86.1766, 
      27.9625}, {-101.709, 36.493}, {-116.687, 45.9611}, {-131.057, 
      56.3311}, {-144.762, 67.5637}, {-157.752, 79.6167}, {-169.977, 
      0.133376}, {73.0254, -2.13778}, {55.3449, -3.32558}, {37.6249, \
-3.42554}, {19.9321, -2.4373}}}, {0, 0}}, {{-1.97567, 
    0.311021}, {1.97567, -0.311021}}], k]

Comment: For cyclic graphs there might be something usable [at this Demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/BerahasConjectureAndCyclicGraphs/)

Comment: @Iris What is `PlanarGraphPL`?  Your graph should consists solely of a list of vertexes and edges.  The spatial locations of the vertexes are irrelevant to the graph structure, and hence to the chromatic number.

Comment: Well, I am using the code from "Mathematica in action, Stan Wagon, Chapter 17 - Great Circle" in order to generate the circles on a sphere. This code has some extra codes and PlanarGraphPL is one of them my code to generate the graph is : {g, g3D} = 
  RandomGreatCircleGraph[2, Include3DPlot -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5], Yellow}];

Comment: @Iris, that doesn't output a `Graph[]` object, which is needed by `ChromaticPolynomial[]`.

Comment: ok, thanks, that is the problem. I will try to generate another graph using basic commands from mathematica and apply your function for chromatic number. Thank you for your hep.