# what replaces MinimumVertexColoring?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

It is straightforward to find the chromatic number of a named graph in Mathematica's database of graphs. What is the simplest way to find a coloring of the vertices corresponding to the chromatic number? This used to be MinimumVertexColoring in earlier versions of Mathematica but this is now obsolete. Many thanks Clive

Comment: Some of these questions and their linked questions might provide a starting point: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189181/how-can-i-compute-the-chromatic-number-of-a-graph https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97714/chromatic-number-for-great-circle-graph?rq=1 I would recommend the IGraph/M package. It's highly efficient and has tons of functions built in: https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM

Comment: As of Mathematica 11.3, there is no built-in replacement for Combinatorica's `MinimumVertexColoring`. However, the implementation in IGraph/M is both fast and written purely in the Wolfram Language. You can not only use it, but also look at the implementation.